# Считать двумерный массив из файла используя BufferedReader

Tags: java, файлы

```
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

            reader.readLine();
            String[] split = reader.readLine().trim().split(" +");
            double[][] arr = new double[split.length][split.length];
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                    String[] split2 = reader.readLine().trim().split(" +");
                    for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {

                        arr[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(split2[j]);

                    }
                }
            }

            return arr;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file");
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Разработать метод, который считывает из текстового файла элементы двумерного массива целых чисел размером **NxN** элементов.

Примечание: Первая строка файла содержит одно целое число **N**. Следующие **N** строк содержат по **N** действительных чисел - элементы заданного массива.

В общем надо написать это на BufferedReader, надо пропустить первую строку (в ней хранится число 100),  а все остальные считать, но в моем варианте выдает ошибку:

```
Cannot invoke "String.trim()" because the return value of "java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()" is null
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ошибка - вы вышли за границу файла, то есть readLine() вернул null. И затем для строки с null вы вызываете trim()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше использовать класс Scanner, в котором можно использовать методы `Scanner::nextInt`, `Scanner::nextDouble`, а также `Scanner::hasNextDouble`, чтобы не выйти за пределы файла в случае, если число строк/данных меньше чем должно быть:

```java
static double[][] readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        double[][] res = new double[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n * n && sc.hasNextDouble(); i++) {
            res[i / n][i % n] = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

---

Если необходимо было воспользоваться именно `BufferedReader` для чтения файла, то каждую строку можно было бы анализировать при помощи сканера вместо разбивания на массив при помощи `String::split`:

```java
static double[][] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        double[][] res = new double[n][n];
        String line;
        int row = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
            for (int i = 0; i < n && sc.hasNextDouble(); i++) {
                res[row][i] = sc.nextDouble();
            }
            row++;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но мне нужно было именно на BufferedReader, и у меня вроде бы уже получилось)

Comment: Тогда можно было бы подобным образом сканировать каждую строку, прочитанную BufferedReader

Answer (score 0):

```
 public double[][] readTwoDimensionalArray(File file) {

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

            double[][] arr = null;
            int row = 0;
            int size = 0;
            reader.readLine();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] split = line.trim().split(" +");

                if (arr == null) {

                    size = split.length;
                    arr = new double[size][size];
                }

                for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {

                    arr[row][col] = Double.parseDouble(split[col]);

                }
             
                row++;
            }

            return arr;

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Error reading file");
            return null;
        }


    }
```